# Set Preceding and Succeeding rows

Tags: r, dplyr

I want all the values in column `values` prior to string "%" should be flagged as "YES". Else "NO". It should be checked by each unique values of column `Id`.

```
df=data.frame('Id'=c(101,101,101,101,102,102,102,102),
              'values'=c('a','%','a','c','a','d','%','c'))
```

All the preceding rows should be flagged as "YES". For example, In Id = 102, YES should be appeared against values "a", "d".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `dplyr` you can use `lead` in conjunction with a vector of values `YES` and `NO`. This assumes you only have one `%` per group. It does not search for last occurrence of `%`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(Id) %>% 
  mutate(flag=values=="%", flag=c("YES", "NO")[cumsum(flag)+1]) %>% 
  ungroup()
# A tibble: 8 × 3
     Id values flag 
  <dbl> <chr>  <chr>
1   101 a      YES  
2   101 %      NO   
3   101 a      NO   
4   101 c      NO   
5   102 a      YES  
6   102 d      YES  
7   102 %      NO   
8   102 c      NO
```

Comment: Thanks. All the preceding rows should be flagged as "YES". For example, In Id = 102, YES should be appeared against values "a", "d".

Comment: @UjjawalBhandari That changes the strategy entirely. Gonna edit...

Comment: @UjjawalBhandari Made some changes, see edit.

Answer (score 1):

With `tidyverse`, we can use `str_detect` with `lead` to determine if `%` is the next value, and if so, then return `1` and if not, `NA`. Then, we can group by `Id` and use `fill` to add `1` to the previous rows. Then, we can convert to `YES` and `NO`.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  mutate(flag = ifelse(str_detect(lead(values), "%"), 1, NA)) %>% 
  group_by(Id) %>% 
  fill(flag, .direction = "up") %>% 
  mutate(flag = ifelse(is.na(flag), "NO", "YES"))

     Id values flag 
  <dbl> <chr>  <chr>
1   101 a      YES  
2   101 %      NO   
3   101 a      NO   
4   101 c      NO   
5   102 a      YES  
6   102 d      YES  
7   102 %      NO   
8   102 c      NO
```

Comment: Thanks. All the preceding rows should be flagged as "YES". For example, In Id = 102, YES should be appeared against values "a", "d".

Comment: @UjjawalBhandari I've updated the answer to reflect that change.